# ajax url to Symfony controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony

I have on a js file an ajax part (I'm a very begginer with ajax)

```
function postRequest() {
var indexArray = getArray();

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: /assets/backend.php,
        data: {
            'indexArray': indexArray
        },
        ....
```

where backend.php is just a small part to test the code, and it works well.

```
<?php
$solution=["item_1","item_3","item_2","item_4","item_5"];

$indexArray=$_POST["indexArray"]; //get user response
if ($solution == $indexArray) {  
    $response->result="s";        //display the response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response->result="f";
echo json_encode($response);
}
```

But I would like to put this part of code of backend.php into my function in my symfony controller.

```
/**
 * @Route("/exercices/{slug}-{id}/play",name="exercice.play",requirements={"slug": "[a-z0-9\-]*"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function play($slug, $id, Request $request)
{
    $exercice = $this->repository->find($id);
    $result = ... // an array with the real solution

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $indexArray = $_POST["indexArray"];
        if ($result == $indexArray) {
            $response->result = "s";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response->result = "f";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('exercice/probleme.html.twig', [
            'solutions' => $result,
            'exercice' => $exercice
        ]);
    }
}
```

And I struggle a lot to do it, I made some research and it seems that the ajax url on a js file cannot be find with path() function like on a twig but even if I put it hard way like this : http://localhost:8000/exercices/un-exo-python-3732/play  but I still got a 500 code error

Has someone know how can I integrate the backend.php code into my controller in the right way ?

---

**EDIT SOLUTION :** Finally, with the help of @PascalYu , we found out that the url should refer to another route in the controller and the relative link begin at the public folder. Also,after that I had an encoding problem with Json.parse() but the real problem was that you need to send a JSON encoded response to the script as :

```
$reponse = new JsonResponse();
    $reponse->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    json_encode(["result" => $result]);
    $reponse->setData(json_encode(["result" => $result]));
    return $reponse;
```

Hope it will help others !

Comment: you can't send a url as localhost to us. can you take a picture?

Comment: The link just show my page correctly, but what I mean is that even to put the link in a "hard way" didn't work ,

Comment: the link works only for you, because it's "localhost".  You can try to open with another computer (or your phone) to check.

Comment: I know it, but what I would like to do is redirect to my symfony controller thanks to this url , I try to put a relative path but it still doesn't work. And I know it's only a path url problem because when I redirect to a simple file .php coded in hard way , not my controller , it works well. So i want to pass it to my symfony controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to get the correct **href**  to the controller for AJAX , is that I use ,first, the **path from twig** . If i use the name of your controller **exercice.play**, I have  :

```
 <div id="path-to-controller" data-href="{{ path('exercice.play', {slug: 'your_slug',id:'your_id'})}}"> </div>
```

Then in the Javascript I get it with **$('#path-to-controller").data("href")** :

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $('#path-to-controller").data("href"),
        data: {
            'indexArray': indexArray
        },
        ....
```

Can you try this?

Comment: Okay , but I don't understand exactly what you want to do ... , Ok for the ajax url but where this div should be ?

Comment: From the twig file that  will call the ajax. How you call the ajax?

Comment: Okay I've done it but still the same error ... I've put the url as you did and the div in the twig file at the end ... I'm desesperating

Comment: I'm still on it , can you show me the error? we can chat if you want  ( you seems french)

Comment: Yes I'm french ! Thanks for your help , how can we chat ? do you have discord ? to show you my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213878/discussion-between-pascal-yu-and-benech17).

Answer (score 0):

I think your Controller must to return a reponse in all cases. You can try this to **debug** :

```
 * @Route("/exercices/{slug}-{id}/play",name="exercice.play",requirements={"slug": "[a-z0-9\-]*"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function play($slug, $id, Request $request)
{
    $exercice = $this->repository->find($id);
    $result = ... // an array with the real solution

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $indexArray = $_POST["indexArray"];
        if ($result == $indexArray) {
            $response->result = "s";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            $response->result = "f";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        return new JsonResponse(['success' => $response]); // If it's an AJAX request

    } 
    return $this->render('exercice/probleme.html.twig', [
            'solutions' => $result,
            'exercice' => $exercice
        ]);
}
```

And add to your $.ajax():

```
success: function (data) {
   console.log(data);
},
```